# How to find the power series representation of $(x+1)\ln(1-x)$ using the geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to find the power series representation of $(x+1)\ln(1-x)$ using the geometric series?

I thought i could multiply the $\ln(1-x)$ through the brackets and than add up the series using manipulation of the geometric series but it didnt quite work?

The answer is $\displaystyle -x-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}x^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle (\ln (1-x))'=-\frac{1}{1-x}$

**Follow up:** It's easy to find $\displaystyle -(x+1)\ln (1-x)=(x+1)\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.

Then $$\begin{align} \displaystyle (x+1)\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}&=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+1}\right)+\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\\
&=\sum \limits_{\color{blue}{n=1}}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n}\right)+\left[\sum \limits _{\color{blue}{n=1}}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)+x\right]\\
&=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n}+\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)+x\\
&\, \vdots\end{align}$$

*(Of course $x$ ranges over $(-1,1)$ throughout).*

Comment: i used that part, and my series representation came out too, $-\Sigma\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ can i just multiply this by $(x+1)$

Comment: Collect coefficients at the  same powers of $x$.

Comment: i still am not able to figure this out, can someone provide me with another hint?

Comment: @lawlipop Added what I think will be enough for you to get the desired result.

Comment: @GitGud thank you!